# How to convert a regex from PCRE to POSIX format, that warns about repetition-operator operand invalid?

Tags: regex, posix, pcre, postfix-mta

Trying to anonymize received headers for relayed messages from authenticated postfix users, there is an example from https://we.riseup.net/debian/anonymizing-postfix:

```
/^Received: from (.* \([-._[:alnum:]]+ \[[.[:digit:]]{7,15}\]\)).*?([[:space:]]+).*\(Authenticated sender: ([^)]+)\).*by (auk\.riseup\.net) \(([^)]+)\) with (E?SMTPS?A?) id ([A-F[:digit:]]+).*/ REPLACE Received: from [127.0.0.1] (localhost [127.0.0.1])$2(Authenticated sender: $3)${2}with $6 id $7
```

When editing the file `regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` the result is an error message:

line 15: **repetition-operator operand invalid**

Now my guess is that the above regex is in PCRE format, where my Postfix requests a POSIX compatible regular expression.

How to make the above regular expression POSIX regexp compliant for use in a Postfix header_checks file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hunch is correct, `.*?` is a PCRE construct: `.*` is normal "any character, as many times as possible, at least zero times", and the trailing question mark changes that to "... as few times as possible ...".  SUSv4 says:

> The behavior of multiple adjacent duplication symbols ( '+' , '*' , '?' , and intervals) produces undefined results.

i haven't studied the pattern too much, but you should be able to work around this particular incompatibility:  the next subpattern is `([[:space:]]+)`, so you should be able to reformulate it as "any *non-space* character...":

```
[^[:space:]]*([[:space:]]+)
```

or maybe just get rid of the problem by omitting the question mark.  the space-eater is followed by another `.*` after all.

Comment: Thank you @just_somebody this helped. The tested to be working POSIX regexp: for postfix became `/^Received: from (.* \([-._a-zA-Z0-9]+ \[[.0-9]{7,15}\]\))(.*[[:space:]]+)\(Authenticated sender: ([^)]+)\)(.*)by (host\.domain\.tld) \(([^)]+)\) with (E?SMTPS?A?) id ([A-F0-9]+)(.*\))/ REPLACE Received: from [127.0.0.1] (localhost [127.0.0.1])$2(Authenticated sender: $3)${4}by $5 ($6) with $7 id $8$9`